# What makes one 'Jagad-Guru'?

Tags: guru

The purport of sloka 207 of chapter 18 of Madhya-khanda of Sri Chaitanya-Charitamrita reads:

> After being initiated, the devotees in the Kṛṣṇa consciousness movement change their names. Whenever a person in the Western world becomes interested in this Kṛṣṇa consciousness movement, he is initiated by this process. **In India we are falsely accused of converting mlecchas and yavanas into the Hindu religion. In India there are many Māyāvādī sannyāsīs known as jagad-guru, although they have hardly visited the whole world**. Some are not even sufficiently educated, yet they make accusations against our movement and accuse us of destroying the principles of the Hindu religion by accepting Mohammedans and yavanas as Vaiṣṇavas. **Such people are simply envious.** We are not spoiling the Hindu system of religion but are simply following in the footsteps of Śrī Caitanya Mahāprabhu by traveling all over the world and accepting those who are interested in understanding Kṛṣṇa as Kṛṣṇadāsa or Rāmadāsa. By the process of a bona fide initiation, their names are changed.

Except Shiva and Sri Krishna, the accepted Jagad-Gurus have been all sannyasins. Does one need to visit the entire world to acquire the Jagad-Guru title ? It is mentioned anywhere in our scriptures or the Mathanamnayas? If not, what makes one 'Jagad-Guru'?

Reference : https://prabhupadabooks.com/cc/madhya/18?page=3&d=1

Comment: Sri Krishna is also considered as Jagadguru. Did he visit the whole world? Obviously no. Why then blame advaitin sannyasis for not visiting the whole world?

Comment: @LazyLubber I could not understand and so asked .